# Google apps script: how to determine screen resolution?

Tags: google-apps-script, resolution

I am trying to create an app in Google apps script, but I want to display different layouts depending on the resolution of the screen (mobile & desktop). However, I can't find anything about how to determine the screen resolution.

Of course I can't determine the screen resolution from the server side, so I tried if I could do something with clientside handlers, but the `ClientHandlers` don't have any method for screen resolution. I also tried to add a manual clientside script to the app using `app.createHTML()`, however Google doesn't allow to include javascript using createHTML.

So how can I get the resolution of the browser using Google apps script?

Comment: You can add JavaScript using createHTML. Read: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service

Comment: I can't access the `window.screen` object using the HtmlService as well. Therefore I still can't determine the screen size and send it to the server.

Comment: the 'windows.screen' does work for me correctly (as of Dec 2015) in htmlservice. Also, google has introduced the 'viewport' property for scaling now. [link](https://plus.google.com/+MarcoColomboMow/posts/GXgRCh98HTu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JavaScript [screen.witdth](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp) property does not work in GAS environment. The Google Caja sanitizer, which is under the hood of GAS, throws the

> Uncaught script error: 'screen is not defined.' in source:
>   'tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref%5fscreen%5fwidth' at line: 7
>   tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref%5fscreen%5fwidth:7: screen is not defined.

exception if to load the following HTML page to the [Caja Playground](http://caja.appspot.com). Probably it is an issue of Caja.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

document.write("Test");
document.write("Total Width: " + screen.width);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

A possible workaround is not to rely upon a screen resolution but to use a user-agent string. This string contains the user browser "id". The [UiApp.getUserAgent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiapp#getUserAgent) method returns it. For instance, Mozilla Firefox on a desktop provides this string like - `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1,gzip(gfe)`. On a mobile phone this string contains `...(Android; Mobile; rv:15.0)...`. A check procedure searches in the returned string the words `Mobile`, `Android`, etc. If one of them found it is a mobile platform and the main code draws a mobile GUI using relative controls sizes. The following code shows how to use it

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel(UiApp.getUserAgent()));
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for commenting on an ancient post/answer, but I'm also having this issue. Unfortunately, `UiApp` was deprecated three years ago: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app#getUserAgent
SadFace.html

Comment: When using `window.screen.width`, you also need to take into account to multiply it with `window.devicePixelRatio`. Otherwise it will return wrong results for HiDPI (Retina) screens.

Comment: getUserAgent() is now available as a method of HtmlService https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#getuseragent

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no known way of doing this UI App. However, using HtmlService in Google Apps Script (not the createHTML() you mentioned), you can add JavaScript and build your entire UI in JavaScript, HTMl and CSS.

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_htmlservice for documentation

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found this in the meantime myself, however I still have one main problem: I can't access the `window.screen` object. The `HtmlService` filters the JS before sending it to the browser and apparently it hides the `window.screen` object and therefore I still can't access the screen size. So the best thing I can do is create the entire app in HTML & CSS using media queries (if supported, haven't tested it) to create different layouts for for different screens.

Comment: @Tiddo Did you get the CSS & media queries to work? I'm trying to do the same thing myself now

Comment: @derekantrican I'm sorry, I can't remember. I haven't touched google apps script in a long long time.

Comment: Trying to design on PC for students on Chromebook. I found this - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp   The @media rule is used in media queries to apply different styles for different media types/devices.

Media queries can be used to check many things, such as:

width and height of the viewport
width and height of the device
orientation (is the tablet/phone in landscape or portrait mode?)
resolution