# optimising web app for IOS using google html service

Tags: html, ios, google-apps-script

I have developed a simple User interface using google app script which is deployed as a web app and utilises a google sheet as a simple database.

This works nicely, however I want to optimise the display for different devices (sizing, stopping iphone from zooming out when displaying it etc.) and potentially add in nice features such as calling the number from phone by pressing a button. I found a [tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/optimizing-mobile-web-apps-ios) that lists how to optimise your web apps using html and decided to try and using the google html functionality to implement it.

It is safe to say my attempt failed. So my questions are

1. Is it possible to do this?
2. Is there a better way of doing this?
3. How do i do it using the html service if it is possible?

Below are my coding attempts (I have left out the bulk of main code as it works and shouldn't affect this part, I can add it in if you think it will help)

my doGet function:

```
function doGet() {

  runHtml();

  // my other code which covers creating UI and searching database

 return app;

}
```

my html function:

```
function runHtml(){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('hbs')
                    .evaluate();
}
```

my html file:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://www.aboutmyarea.co.uk/images/imgstore/122_8820olyyxq.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="http://www.aboutmyarea.co.uk/images/imgstore/122_8820olyyxq.png">

</head>

<body>

</body>
```

** EDIT **

I found a solution for the task of calling a number by pressing a link (rather simple in hind sight)

```
var anchor = app.createAnchor("a link", "tel:01462629065");
panel.add(anchor,300,50);
```

Comment: what is this 'return app' doing in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have run into a known complaint with the caja sanitization used by the HtmlService, [Issue 1632](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1632). Visit and star it to receive updates.

In the mean time, these answers contain alternative suggestions:

- [Google apps script: how to determine screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760135/google-apps-script-how-to-determine-screen-resolution/12776603#12776603)
- [How do I dynamically adjust css stylesheet based on browser width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962837/how-do-i-dynamically-adjust-css-stylesheet-based-on-browser-width)

PS: Best practice: [Don't use html, head or body tags](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#dont_use_html_head_or_body_tags) in HtmlService pages.

Comment: from reading that response it would appear that google has no intention of adding in some native functionality to deal with this?

Comment: I can't guess at their intent. (I don't work for Google.) Google Sites [supports mobile device displays](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/1368620?hl=en), though - so for Google Apps users, at least, there is an answer.