# Alternative to UiApp.getUserAgent()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760135/google-apps-script-how-to-determine-screen-resolution#answer-12776603) to a question I had, but unfortunately, [it's been deprecated since 3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760135/google-apps-script-how-to-determine-screen-resolution#comment-78745476). What are my options for getting that user agent string?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [they moved the method to `HtmlService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#getUserAgent()).